# Are eidim lawyers?

Tags: halacha, edim-witnesses

Are [eidim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness) considered lawyers?

Comment: Why do you think that witnesses are lawyers based on which Gemara in Makkos?

Comment: can you explain why you might think that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, eidim are witnesses, not lawyers. Their function is to give testimony as to what they observed, not to serve as a partisan defender of one side or another.

Nevertheless, in a criminal case it might be argued that the eidim who witnessed the crime are effectively the prosecutors, but I think it is more accurate to simply call them accusers.